# I want the code to get this output : lee[2],rebok[2];

Tags: java

```java
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add("lee");
arrayList.add("lee");
arrayList.add("rebok");
arrayList.add("rebok");

Set set = new LinkedHashSet(arrayList);
```

I want the code to get this output :

```java
lee[2],rebok[2];
```

Comment: `System.out.println("lee[2],reebok[2]");`... (this site is not a code "factory")

Comment: I think you are looking for a `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: What issues are you having? And BTW, a `LinkedList` cannot be assigned to a `Set` reference.

Comment: you are adding "rebok" and want o/p as "reebok"(check spelling).
And what is that of LinkedList assigned to a Set additional to @RohitJain s comment there is no inheritance relation b/w Set and List

Answer (score 0):

Using [guava `Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) for counting

```
final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
final Multiset<String> count = HashMultiset.create(arrayList); // your arraylist
for (final String key : count.elementSet()) {
    out.append(key).append('[').append(count.count(key)).append("],");
}
// we need to remove a possible trailing comma
System.out.println(out.length() > 0 ? out.substring(0, out.length() - 1) : "");
```

output:

```
lee[2],rebok[2]
```